# best / better way to read / write arrays to firebase

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to find how to write/read arrays from my Firebase and I ended up with this. When I write I do:

```
String RestaurantIDs = "";
for(String RestaurantID : category.getRestaurantIDs()) { RestaurantIDs += RestaurantID + ","; }
DataToSave.put(CategoryFireBase.RestaurantIDs, "[" + RestaurantIDs + "]");
```

And when I read I do:

```
ArrayList<String> restaurantIDs = new ArrayList<>();
String[] Temp_restaurantIDs = document.get(CategoryFireBase.RestaurantIDs).toString().replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",");
for (String value : Temp_restaurantIDs){restaurantIDs.add(value);}
```

And I have 2 questions about it.

1. Is it ok that I'm saving it as long string instead of arrays?
2. If there is a way to read and write the array as an actual array, is it better then this?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is it ok that I'm saving it as long string instead of arrays?

There is nothing wrong with that but it's more convenient to use arrays. For example, if you have in the database an array of restaurant ids, when you make a `get()` call, you can get that arrays directly as a list, without the need to split that long String.

> 2. If there is a way to read and write the array as an actual array, is it better then this?

Is it better because you can use specialized methods to update or remove elements within an array, as explained in the official documentation:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Comment: thanks for the response, can you give me an example of code of how to write and array and how to read one? when I tried to do `get()` to the arrays it returned it as an object so I don't know how to convert it to an array, and last just to make sure my array looks like this, [link](http://prntscr.com/r6zaq0).

Comment: I cannot write code for you. You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up.